Problema al compilar tgbot-cpp con msys
Estoy buscando una manera de programar bots para telegram usando C++, con la librería tgbot-cpp. Dado que no uso Visual Studio sino Code (y por tanto no me funciona vcpkg), intenté construirla por MSYS, para ello seguí los siguientes pasos (todo desde la consola de MSYS2 mingw64 en modo administrador, ya que tengo instalado ese compilador):

Cloné el repositorio

git clone https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp


Descargué las dependencias, en todos los casos la versión de mingw-w64-x86_64

pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-boost
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
pacman -S libcurl

(Para esta última no había al parecer versión de mingw64, salvo para Python)

Entro al proyecto y lo configuro con cmake

cd tgbot-cpp
mkdir Build
cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles" -B Build

Cmake detecta todas las dependencias y genera sin problemas la configuración en la carpeta Build. Luego construyo la librería, y todo sale bien
cd Build
cmake --build .

En este punto tengo el archivo .a de la librería en la carpeta Build y los includes afuera, así que para que el compilador los detecte, los copio manualmente a usr/local/lib e include respectivamente (si existe para ello una mejor práctica, aclárenmelo).
El problema surge cuando intento compilar un bot con la librería recién construida, para ello voy a la carpeta tgbot-cpp/samples e intento compilar el bot de ejemplo echobot, nuevamente ejecuto cmake:
cd samples/echobot
mkdir Build
cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles" -B Build
cd Build
cmake --build .

En este punto me sale el siguiente error:
mingw32-make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/lib/libTgBot.a', needed by 'echobot.exe'.  Stop.

Como sé que libTgBot.a existe de hecho en /usr/local/, pero al copiarla ahí me pareció muy extraño que la carpeta "local" no existiese antes en usr (de modo que tuve que crearla), me persigno y copio tanto los includes como libTgBot.a en el directorio del propio compilador, es decir, en msys2/mingw64/include y lib, respectivamente. Como me sigue dando el mismo error, vuelvo a leer la documentación de la librería en github y en la parte de instalación en windows, donde dice "Setup projects with CMakeLists", cambio el archivo CMakeLists.txt del echobot de acuerdo a las instrucciones que ahí se encuentran, de forma que las dos líneas modificadas quedan así:
# Línea 13
include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}) 
# Línea 21
target_link_libraries(echobot TgBot.a ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})

Una vez hecho esto, regreso a echobot, elimino la carpeta Build y ejecuto de nuevo los comandos que puse más arriba. Esta vez, los resultados son bien distintos, y para mí incomprensibles:
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/echobot.dir/src/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable echobot.exe
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\echobot.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7startupERNS2_4dataEhh[_ZN5boost4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7startupERNS2_4dataEhh]+0x74): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\echobot.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7cleanupERNS2_4dataE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7cleanupERNS2_4dataE]+0x35): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text+0x485): undefined reference to `__imp_select'C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text+0x49e): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops16clear_last_errorEv[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops16clear_last_errorEv]+0x10): undefined reference to `__imp_WSASetLastError'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops14get_last_errorERNS_6system10error_codeEb[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops14get_last_errorERNS_6system10error_codeEb]+0x38): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops5closeEyRhbRNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops5closeEyRhbRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0xaa): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops5closeEyRhbRNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops5closeEyRhbRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x152): undefined reference to `__imp_ioctlsocket'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops5closeEyRhbRNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops5closeEyRhbRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x174): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops4recvEyP7_WSABUFyiRNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops4recvEyP7_WSABUFyiRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x5d): undefined reference to `__imp_WSARecv'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops4sendEyPK7_WSABUFyiRNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops4sendEyPK7_WSABUFyiRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x5b): undefined reference to `__imp_WSASend'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops6socketEiiiRNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops6socketEiiiRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x3d): undefined reference to `__imp_WSASocketW'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops6socketEiiiRNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops6socketEiiiRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x9c): undefined reference to `__imp_setsockopt'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops9poll_readEyhiRNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops9poll_readEyhiRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x186): undefined reference to `__imp_select'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops10poll_writeEyhiRNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops10poll_writeEyhiRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x185): undefined reference to `__imp_select'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops12poll_connectEyiRNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops12poll_connectEyiRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x1da): undefined reference to `__imp_select'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops9inet_ntopEiPKvPcymRNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops9inet_ntopEiPKvPcymRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0xe5): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAAddressToStringA'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops9inet_ptonEiPKcPvPmRNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops9inet_ptonEiPKcPvPmRNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x79): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStringToAddressA'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops24translate_addrinfo_errorEi[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops24translate_addrinfo_errorEi]+0x1e3): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops11getaddrinfoEPKcS4_RK8addrinfoPPS5_RNS_6system10error_codeE[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops11getaddrinfoEPKcS4_RK8addrinfoPPS5_RNS_6system10error_codeE]+0x7e): undefined reference to `__imp_getaddrinfo'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops12freeaddrinfoEP8addrinfo[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops12freeaddrinfoEP8addrinfo]+0x16): undefined reference to `__imp_freeaddrinfo'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops20network_to_host_longEm[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops20network_to_host_longEm]+0x13): undefined reference to `__imp_ntohl'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops20host_to_network_longEm[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops20host_to_network_longEm]+0x13): undefined reference to `__imp_htonl'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops12call_connectIiEEiMNS2_6msghdrET_yPKvy[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops12call_connectIiEEiMNS2_6msghdrET_yPKvy]+0x2f): undefined reference to `__imp_connect'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops15call_setsockoptIiEEiMNS2_6msghdrET_yiiPKvy[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops15call_setsockoptIiEEiMNS2_6msghdrET_yiiPKvy]+0x3e): undefined reference to `__imp_setsockopt'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops15call_getsockoptIiEEiMNS2_6msghdrET_yiiPvPy[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops15call_getsockoptIiEEiMNS2_6msghdrET_yiiPvPy]+0x40): undefined reference to `__imp_getsockopt'
C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libTgBot.a(BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp.obj):BoostHttpOnlySslClient.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops16call_getpeernameIiEEiMNS2_6msghdrET_yPvPy[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops16call_getpeernameIiEEiMNS2_6msghdrET_yPvPy]+0x37): undefined reference to `__imp_getpeername'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\echobot.dir\build.make:102: echobot.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/echobot.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2

Vale aclarar que también intenté la compilación del bot sin CMake. En mi caso, debido a las modificaciones que tuve que hacer, mi línea de comandos fue la siguiente:
g++ main.cpp -o echobot --std=c++14 -L/usr/local/lib -lTgBot -lboost_system-mt -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread

Sin embargo, esto último da los mismos errores que puse arriba (como era de esperar).
Creo que he dejado claro el esfuerzo que he pasado en vano para compilar esta librería :")
¿Alguien que pueda ayudarme?

Creo que te saltaste algunos pasos. Seguro que seguiste las instrucciones correctas al pie de la letra?
